# How to use a GUI tool to administer a SQLite database on a virtual machine

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ssh, sqlite

I know how to do this for MySQL.

I am using Mac OS X 10.7.5

I run VirtualBox with the guest OS as 12.10 Ubuntu Server edition.

Inside the Ubuntu, I installed mySQL and SQLite3.

MySQL runs on the usual 3306 port in the Ubuntu.

Using the port forwarding feature in VirtualBox, I port-forwarded port 3122 on the host OS(Lion) to the ssh port 22 on the guest OS(Ubuntu).

I run the software Sequel Pro on my Macbook which has a SSH access option.

See screenshot.

[image]

Using this method, I can administer the mySQL databases on the Ubuntu Server where I run my web application development.

How do I administer the SQLite3 databases in a similar way?

I have downloaded the SQLite3 Database Browser, but there is no SSH option as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the app comes with SSH tunnelling capabilities you are out of luck. Still here are a few alternatives for you to try:

- You can use a native app inside the VM. SQLite3 Database Browser is available for Ubuntu as well.
- Since sqlite databases are basically files you could mount the VM as an SSH volume on your Mac and open the file with SQLite3 Database Browser.

Comment: Basically the key is to understand that sqlites a file so I can simply use Database Browser